# Datatable warning message on slick carousel: "DataTables warning: Non-table node initialisation (DIV)"

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Hi everyone I trying to use the jQuery Slick carousel and when I started the slick a warning alert appears. **$('#lista-anuncios').slick()**
How i prevent this alert? I tried to overwrite the alert message with this: ***alert() = function(){}***. I don't have any datatable reference on my project. I thinking the slick project has a datatable reference, but how I fix it?
[Warning alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDCiW.png)

And the problem is:

```
    <div class="header-classificados">
        <h1 class="page-title" style="margin-left: 56px; padding: 22px 0">Classificados</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="page-content-container">

    <div class="anun-form">

        <div class="filtro">
            <label>Exibindo:</label>
            <div class="ui dropdown" id="dropFiltro">
                <div class="default text" data-value="all">
                    Todos
                </div>
                <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                <div class="menu">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="anun-right">
            <a href="@Url.Action("classificados", "intranet")" class="voltar">
                <img src="~/Imagens/site/double_back_arrow_cmg.svg" /> Ver todos
            </a>

            <button class="ui button anunciar" id="btn-anunciar">
                <img src="~/Imagens/site/bullhorn_cmg.svg" /> Quero anunciar
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="lista-anuncios"></div>



<script>
$('#lista-anuncios').slick({
                infinite: false,
                dots: true,
                arrows: true,
                variableWidth: false,
                adaptiveHeight: false,
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 3
            });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: This error has nothing to do with slickjs. Somewhere in your code `DataTable` method i is used ( from jquery dataTables plugin )  . Something like `$("notTable").DataTable ( { ... } )` search for that line and change the element you apply DataTable on to be a table. not a div.

Comment: @ChrisG I'll try to create that later, thank you!

Comment: @MihaiT when I debugging the alert message appears after this point  $('#lista-anuncios').slick({ ... });

Comment: I discover the problem, Thank you for trying to help. It was a jqruery bundle at the wrong location.